# Getting the key in every JSON object

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

I am fairly new to Vue and JS but I am making API calls and getting a JSON response then sending the response to an empty array. How do I get the ID of each object in the array?

The array that the response is being pushed to is structured like this

```
groups: [
  {
    "id": "0",
    "name": "a",
    "price": 5
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "b",
    "price": 5
  },
  { 
    "id": "2",
    "name": "c",
    "price": 5
  }
]
```

I'd like to pull the Id of each object and push the values to an empty array

```
for(var group in this.groups) {
  if (this.groups.hasOwnProperty(0)) {
    this.group = this.groups[0];
    this.groupsId.push(this.innerObj);
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is saying *Cannot read property '0' of undefined at eval*
Ideally I'd like an array that has all the Ids of each object.

Answer (score 2):

`this.groups.hasOwnProperty(0)` should be `group.hasOwnProperty('id')`

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over an array of objects and collect every ID into a new array:

```js
const res = {
  groups: [{
      "id": "0",
      "name": "a",
      "price": 5
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "b",
      "price": 5
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "c",
      "price": 5
    }
  ]
};

const ids = res.groups.map(obj => {    // you use this.groups
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty('id')) return  obj.id;
});

console.log(ids)
```

Comment: Should it be `group.hasOwnProperty('id')`?

Comment: I'm talking about your first sentence, where you were trying to correct the existing code. `groups` is an array. It doesn't have a property named `id`.

Comment: @Rainbolt uhh thanks I thought you were referring to the example code

Comment: @justarookie you're welcome. And thanks to Rainbolt for the eagle-eye.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
this.groupsId = this.groups.map(i => i.id);
```

If you already have elements in `this.groupsId` you can append the ids using [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
this.groupsId = this.groupsId.concat(this.groups.map(i => i.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to loop and check if there's `id`.

```js
const groups = [
  {"name": "a","price": 5},
  {"id": "1","name": "b","price": 5},
  { "id": "2","name": "c","price": 5}
];
const list = groups.reduce((groupIds, group) => group.id ? [...groupIds, group.id] : groupIds, []);
console.log(list);
```